# Pupeteer: How to specify Chromium path on Linux

Tags: puppeteer

I am on a Linux environment, and I would like to find how to specify the path it should use for Chromium. At the minute, here is the error I am having:

```
Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn
           install" Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm
           install" or "yarn install" at Launcher.launch
```

I did disable the download on purpose by, using the variable `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD` however, I haven't found how to give the path to my chromium binary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specify the path to the Chromium binary, using the option `executablePath` when calling [`puppeteer.launch`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions).

**Quote form the docs:**

> `executablePath`: Path to a Chromium or Chrome executable to run instead of the bundled Chromium. If `executablePath` is a relative path, then it is resolved relative to current working directory. **BEWARE**: Puppeteer is only guaranteed to work with the bundled Chromium, use at your own risk.

**Code Sample**

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/path/to/binary',
    /* ... */
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Puppeteer will look for the environment variable `PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH`.

So to specify the path to Chromium (or Firefox if you prefer) run `export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser`.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my problem with

```
 export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

And then if you are trying to get mermaid.cli work (mmdc), the second problem I hit was a sandbox error, which I fixed with:

```
echo '{ "args":["--no-sandbox"] }' > puppeteer.json
mmdc -i input.mmd -o output.svg -p puppeteer.json
```

The error before this fix was:

```
 (node:23266) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
 [0223/152312.185004:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without -- 
 no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```